# how to verify a firebase admin on backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement middleware in an express server that sets custom uid/admin headers on the incoming request. This modified request will then be used after the middleware to see if an authenticated user/admin is accessing that particular resource.

To do this for a client, I just grab the token on the Authorization header and feed it into the firebase admin api's verifyIdToken method. If a uid exists, I set the header. For example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  /* get rid of headers sent in by malicious users. */
  delete req.headers._uid;
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    _dps.fb_admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(claims => {
      if (claims.uid) { req.headers._uid = claims.uid; }
      next();
    }).catch(err => next());
  } catch(err) { next(); }
});
```

Two questions:

1) As an admin with a service account on another server, how would I send a request to this server such that this server can determine an admin sent the request?

2) How would I identify the admin on this server?

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to create your own custom Firebase token to include custom fields such as `isAdmin: true` in the JWT. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
2. See (1)

Comment: Yes but once I create the token, I need to sign in using the client sdk and get the id token that generates. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think I can sign in with the node admin sdk.

Comment: Correct on the first part and correct on the second. The Admin SDK doesn't use the client side SDK auth methods. You'll use a `service account` as specified here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

Comment: I'm aware of how to initialize the sdk with the service account. I'm just not sure how this solves my problem :/.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`setCustomUserClaims()` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to add a special "admin" claim to all admin user accounts, and check for it when verifying ID tokens. You can find a discussion and a demo of this use case [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlmizBWJk6A) (jump ahead to the 6:45 mark of the recording).

Comment: This assumes I want to have accounts with admin roles, which I don't. I'm looking for a way to use the service account. This should be possible since i can write to the RTDB with the node admin api and the RTDB knows its an admin requesting the write.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution would be to simply generate an API key of decent length and set it as an environment variable on each of my servers. I could then send this in the Authorization header whenever i want to make an admin https request and verify it in the middleware of the receiver by doing a simple string compare. The only people that could see this API key are those that have access to my servers (AKA admins). Let me know if something is wrong with this approach. It sure seems simple.